# What is the meaning of the 'tag' in Git repository and how 'tag' works?

Tags: git, version-control, repo

I am new to Git Repository. And I don't know about 'tag'. how it works and what can we get from tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a specific commit is just identified by a hash-code, such as 5h45h32. If you want to give this commit another, more readable name, use tagging: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: I'll also add that if you are more familiar with CVS or Subversion, tags in Git are a bit different. Carefully read through the manual @Mattias linked you to. Git can be quite a learning curve at first, but it's really worth it to spend time getting intimately familiar with it. I also recommend going through the [Interactive Git Tutorial](https://try.github.io/) on GitHub.

Comment: I love your example of '5h45h32' for a hash and especially the fact that there can't be a 'h' in a hexa number...